# Data manipulation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am currently using Matlab to plot some data using the stairs command:

```
[x,y]=stairs(a,b)
```

where a and b are my input data. However, for plotting reasons I need to use the command:

```
plot(x,y,'-ok')
```

I can see I have a lot of duplicate values (in the a and b source vector there are duplicate values, but I cannot delete any of those).

Is there any way to remove the intermediate duplicate values from x and y?
Let's say that I have from the stairs command:

```
x=1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
y=0 10 10 20 20 30 30 40
```

and I want to obtain

```
x=1 1 2 2
y=0 20 20 40
```

basically I want to save the last first pair of x,y values for each different value of x.
I already tried with some for and if cycles but I cannot remove all the duplicates.

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE: thanks @BrendanFrick, however using this

```
x=[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]';
y=[0 10 10 20 20 30 30 40]';

% Column one is x, column two is y
u = [x y]';

% Show every combination of x and y exactly once
v = unique(u','rows');

w = [];
for i = unique(x)
   % Need to allocate two rows for each unique x value
   ind = (find(unique(x) == i)*2)-1;

   % Store the min and max 
   w(ind:ind+1,:) = [i,min(v(v(:,1) == i,2));...
                        i,max(v(v(:,1) == i,2))];
end

% Remove duplicates (i.e. min and max y are the same for an x)
w = unique(w,'rows');
x = w(:,1);
y = w(:,2);
```

Im getting an error: Matrix dimensions must agree. in this line:

```
w(ind:ind+1,:) = [i,min(v(v(:,1) == i,2));...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each value of `x` occurs at least two times, find the indices where values are changing and the indices next to them. Include the first and last indices since these will always be included.

```
ind = find(logical(diff(x)));    ind = [1 ind ind+1];   %indices
x = x([ind end]);                y = y([ind end]);      %required updated values
```

Comment: In the question you showed a row matrix, in above case you have a column matrix. so you need semicolons`;` i.e. `[1; ind; ind+1];` and `[ind;end]`

Comment: btw just to confirm, you have each value of `x` at least two times right? And there will  never be  single value of `x`?

Comment: I also assumed that. However if you had something like x=[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3]` i.e. 3 is only once. so you would have to do some extra tweaking but that's not your case. Cheers

Comment: Man you have no idea! Thanks a lot <3<3<3